# wordpress menu organization went wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

Picture 1
[image: Menu Organization order]

Picture 2
[image: appears in this way]
Picture 3

[image: My function code]
Picture 4
[image: my header.php]

I want to organize my menu order in the way picture 1 shows 
but it appears in the way picture 2 shows 
picture 3 has my functions.php 
and picture 4 has my header.php file

Comment: Instead of images put the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to click on the option saying "Header menu " 
after clicking on that it works fine !! 
[image]

You also forget to edit organize the menus go to admin and organize theme by drag up and down

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the header.php

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
  'theme_location' => 'nav-menu'
) );
```

Code in function.php

```
register_nav_menus( array( 
  'nav-menu' => esc_html__( 'Nav Menu', 'themename'), 
) );
```

This is the proper way to make a navbar in wordpress.